# I am trying to setup of a webhook using Stripe and NextJS 14.0.3

Tags: typescript, next.js, stripe-payments, next.js14

**This is my stripe webhook (I am using Next.js 14 and trying to implement payment using stripe)**

this file is stripe-webhook and I double check the file path don't know the error

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
import { buffer } from "stream/consumers"
import Stripe from "stripe"

export const config = {
    api:{
        bodyParser: false
    }
}

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY as string,{
    apiVersion: '2023-10-16'
})

export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse
){

    const buf = await buffer(req)
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature']

    if(!sig){
        return res.status(400).send("Missing the stripe signature!")
    }

    let event: Stripe.Event

    try{
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
            buf, sig, process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET!
        )
    }catch(err){
        return res.status(400).send("Webhook error" + err)
    }

    switch(event.type){
        case 'charge.succeeded':
            const charge: any = event.data.object as Stripe.Charge;
            if(typeof charge.payment_intent === 'string'){
                await prisma?.order.update({
                    where: {paymentIntentId: charge.payment_intent},
                    data: {status: "complete", address: charge.shipping?.address},
                });
            }
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Unhandled event type:" + event.type)
    }
    res.json({received: true})
}
```

**But I got this error! the file path is ok**

```
> Ready! You are using Stripe API Version [2023-10-16]. Your webhook signing secret is whsec_ae0f6c1ba90b1c434264f36f618f9238a3ecb8e6b8de8a5f6ff278d99f30d0cd (^C to quit)
2023-12-04 18:06:24   --> payment_intent.created [evt_3OJbNsGRtGZJ0dW50BaY3sq1]
2023-12-04 18:06:25  <--  [404] POST http://localhost:3000/pages/api/stripe-webhook [evt_3OJbNsGRtGZJ0dW50BaY3sq1]
2023-12-04 18:06:26   --> payment_intent.created [evt_3OJbNtGRtGZJ0dW50ZnH99Dz]
2023-12-04 18:06:26  <--  [404] POST http://localhost:3000/pages/api/stripe-webhook [evt_3OJbNtGRtGZJ0dW50ZnH99Dz]
```

***please help me to fix this error!***

Comment: looks like you are using the pages router from the URL in the log. In this case, URL should be without `pages` -> `http://localhost:3000/api/stripe-webhook`

Comment: then I got `2023-12-04 20:06:46  <--  [500] POST http://localhost:3000/api/stripe-webhook [evt_3OJdFJGRtGZJ0dW53oUgnA57]`

Comment: At least you get to the endpoint. Please provide an update to the question with details on the error